# .net core console application logging filter via appsetting.json

Tags: logging, console-application, app-config, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to setup logging for my .net core console app. I am hoping to control the logging filter option using `appsetting.json`. It is not working, but not sure why. Here are the project setting.

```xml
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="5.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
      </ItemGroup>
    
    </Project>
```

appsetting.json

```json
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Debug",
          "System": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Debug"
        },
        "Console": {
          "IncludeScopes": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

Program.cs

```cs
    using FlaggerDocUpload;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IServiceCollection services = ConfigureServices();
                var servicesProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    
                servicesProvider.GetService<App>().Run(args);
            }
    
            private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
            {
                IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    
                var config = LoadConfiguraton();
    
                services.AddSingleton(config);
    
                var v = config.GetSection("Logging");
                services.AddLogging(configure => {
                    configure
                        .AddConfiguration(v)
                        .AddConsole()
                        .AddDebug();
                    });
                services.AddTransient<App>();
    
                return services;
                
            }
    
            public static IConfiguration LoadConfiguraton()
            {
                return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .Build();
            }
        }
    }
```

app.cs

```cs
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace FlaggerDocUpload
    {
        class App
        {
            private readonly ILogger<App> logger;
    
            public App(ILogger<App> logger)
            {
                this.logger = logger;
            }
    
            public void Run(string[] args)
            {
                this.logger.LogInformation("hello Info");
                this.logger.LogWarning("hello Warning");
                this.logger.LogCritical("hello Critical");
                this.logger.LogDebug("hello Debug");
                this.logger.LogTrace("hello Trace");
                this.logger.LogError("hello Error");
                Console.WriteLine("Hello from APP");
    
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                foreach (string arg in args)
                    Console.WriteLine(arg);
    
                Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

It does not matter whatever I set in the appsetting.js the output is remain same. in the console. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This ought to do the trick.

Of note is that you need to dispose of the ServiceProvider or some of the log output may not get flushed to the console.

ConsoleLogging.csproj

```xml
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="5.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>  
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
      </ItemGroup>
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
    </Project>
```

appsettings.json

```json
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Debug"
        }
      }
    }
```

Program.cs

```cs
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    namespace ConsoleLogging
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using var di = new DependencyInjection();
                di.Initialize();
                var p = di.GetService<Program>();
                p.Run();
            }
    
            public ILogger<Program> Logger { get; }
    
            public Program(ILogger<Program> logger)
            {
                Logger = logger;
            }
    
            private void Run()
            {
                Logger.LogCritical("Critical");
                Logger.LogError("Error");
                Logger.LogWarning("Warning");
                Logger.LogInformation("Information");
                Logger.LogDebug("Debug");
                Logger.LogTrace("Trace");
            }
        }
    
        internal class DependencyInjection : IDisposable
        {
            private ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
            private bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    
            public void Initialize()
            {
                if (IsInitialized)
                {
                    return;
                }
                IsInitialized = true;
    
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
                                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
                                       .Build();
    
                ServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                                     .AddLogging(config =>
                                                 {
                                                     _ = config.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                                                               .AddConsole();
                                                 })
                                     .AddTransient<Program>()
                                     .BuildServiceProvider();
            }
    
            public T GetService<T>()
            {
                if (!IsInitialized)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Need to call Initialize() on the DependencyInjection instance");
                }
                var service = ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
                return service;
            }
    
            public void Dispose()
            {
                ServiceProvider?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Console Output]